# Laravel Sanctum - Unathenticated after login

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-sanctum

I've built a small web app locally using laravel 8 sanctum and vue.

Both locally and on the prod server I'm using docker so everything is the same. The code is running on a subdomain sub.my-domain.com

**All works fine locally.**

The issue I have is when running the code on live server.

I first send a request too `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` which returns a `204` response code but no cookies are set - this is where the issue is I believe as when running this locally the `XSRF-TOKEN` is set.

Login method within VueX:

```
    login: function ({ commit }, data) {
      axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie', { withCredentials: true })
        .then(response => {
          axios.post('api/login', {
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password
          })
            .then(response => {
              if (response.data.success) {
                commit('setUser', response.data);
                // router.go('/sales-dashboard')

              } else {
                console.log(response.data.message)
              }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.error(error);
            });
        })
    },
```

.env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=my-domain.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=.my-domain.com
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false;
```

config/sanctum.php

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,.my-domain.com, sub.my-domain.com',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as it all works fine locally so it must be something to do with the config.

To clarify, the actual login endpoint works fine. But when going to a route behind the sanctum middleware I get an unauthenticated message.

Please let me know where I'm going wrong

Thank you

Comment: Update. This perticular issue was caused by CORS not being set correctly, look at your session.php file and investigate your set cookies in the network tab of inspector tools which helped me debug.. I now have the cookies being set, BUT I'm still getting unathenticated errors for routes using sanctum middleware.

Comment: It is curious to see how your sanctum.php stateful variable does not include the frontend URL. In Laravel 10 the sprintf() has 3 parameters to include it.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was down to CORS and the sanctum set up.

2 Things to check if you face a smiliar issue.

1 - CORS - Check your `session.php` file and if you're not using SSL set `secure` to `false` and make sure `same_site` is `lax`.

2 - Sanctum config - Check `sanctum.php` and make sure your domain is part of the `stateful` key (I use a subdomain, so I used sub.domain.com (no port or protocol)). Also check your `.env` and check

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=sub.domain.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com
```

the leading `.` on `SESSION_DOMAIN` is a wildcard I believe.

Once all this was done it was all working.

Comment: Another thing to check here is if you're using axios. Make sure you're doing the following before any request: ```axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;```

Comment: Thank you a billion times. I was struggling to make this work in production. My problem was in settting the SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS and SESSION_DOMAIN correctly.

Comment: Thank you, same here. Problem was not properly setting session domain & stateful domains although session driver was also set to file. Changed as above and it works in production..!